# Input to a Java program - keyboard input v/s file

Tags: java, input, console

I have a Java program that accepts input text typed in from standard input

is there a way to find if the user has typed in the text or redirected input from a file?

$ java prog
this text is typed in from the keyboard

$ java prog < file.txt

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you wanting to know where the input is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the [JLine source code](http://jline.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jline/jline/src/main/java/jline/), you have to use JNI to make native OS calls to determine whether stdin is a TTY. If you're certain to be in a Unix-like environment, you can [do what they do there](http://jline.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jline/jline/src/main/java/jline/UnixTerminal.java?revision=1.17&view=markup).